# jQuery Fancybox trigger not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I am opening fancybox automatic when page load and for this, I am using trigger method with a hidden link inside the page, The problem is fancybox popup loading but its missing overlay, just that overlay is not opening.

I am using **fancyBox v2.1.5**

This is the code I am using

```
$(".login_signup_lb").fancybox({
    maxWidth: 450,
    autoSize: true,
    fitToView: true,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    closeBtn: false,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)'
            }
        }
    }
}).trigger("click");
```

This is the html code which is hidden in the page

```
<a id="login_signup" class="login_signup_lb fancybox.ajax" href="fileurl.html" style="display:none;">
  Lightbox
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trigger after creating `fancybox`

```
$(".fancybox.ajax").eq(0).trigger('click');
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Py2RA/) is jsfiddle

Comment: @SanjeevK Thanks a lot